# Parameter missing error on image upload swift

Tags: ios, swift2, image-uploading, multipartform-data, image-upload

I'm trying to upload an image to server with some details, but I'm keep on receiving parameter missing error from the server. This is my image upload code

```
 func uploadImages(imageData: NSData, withParams requestDict:NSDictionary, callBack:(responseDict: NSDictionary?, error: NSError?) -> ())
    {

        print(requestDict)            
        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: String(format: "%@%@", BASE_URL, IMAGE_UPLOAD_API))!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval          = FLOAT_CONSTANT_60
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

         request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(requestDict as? [String : String], filePathKey: "image", imageData: imageData, boundary: boundary)

        print(requestDict)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
            do {
                let JSON = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                guard let JSONDictionary :NSDictionary = JSON as? NSDictionary else {
                    print("Not a Dictionary")
                    //get your JSONData here from dictionary.

                    return
                }
                callBack(responseDict: JSON as? NSDictionary, error: nil)
                print("JSONDictionary! \(JSONDictionary)")

            }
            catch let JSONError as NSError {
                print("\(JSONError)")
                callBack(responseDict: nil, error: JSONError)

            }

        })

     }


    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageData: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData()

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "MyImage.jpg"

        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendData(imageData)
        body.appendString("\r\n")

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body

    }

    /// Create boundary string for multipart/form-data request
    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
    }
```

This is my server api format

```
"{
'deviceId' : 1234567,
'role' : 'admin',
'authToken' : 'cf01ebcd5844fde166940b06fbb267ba',
'userId' : 90490,
'appointmentId': 25067187,
'position' : 2,
'image' : ''
}"
```

And this is what the print response prints in the uploadImages method

```
{
    appointmentId = 25067187;
    authToken = b72e4d89aa53399dd3a04f1440dec704;
    deviceId = "4DF3R180-55XC-4G3C-90F8-3431537ECCAF";
    position = 2;
    role = admin;
    userId = 90490;
}
```

I believe the image parameter is the filePathKey string and gets attached in the request but I'm not able to print it to see the request after attaching the image. Is there something I'm doing wrong due to which the image parameter is not getting added?

## EDIT

This is how I call the method

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage!, 1)

            let apiHandler = APIHandler()

            apiHandler.uploadImages(imageData!, withParams: self.createImageUploadDict(), callBack: { (responseDict, error) -> () in
                print(responseDict)


            })

        })
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You never show us how `imageData` is generated. Is it properly encoded? Also this may very well be an issue specific to the API you're using and you don't tell us what that is. Hard to help.

Comment: I'm using  imagepickerconroller, I've updated the code. Can u check if this code is working with any other api?

Comment: No, that's your job :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, there was nothing wrong with the code, while creating the request dictionary I was actually using [String: AnyObject] but here I used [String:String] so thats why I got the parameter missing error.